# Can't get pagination to work for scrolling website

Tags: jquery, pagination, bind, horizontal-scrolling

I have a horizontal scrolling website and i cant get the nav links to stay active when each section comes into view. What I mean is i got them to work once but when i refresh the page they disapper and when you first come to the site the showing div link is not active. I've tried several methods from this site but with no luck. Help please!

Here is the code that is not correct (i am a jquery/javascript noob):

```
$('a.panel').bind('click',function(event){
    $('a.panel').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

my html is this:

```
<nav>
    <li><a href="#1" class="panel">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2" class="panel">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3" class="panel">work</a></li>
</nav>

<div id="content">
    <div id="mask">
        <section id="1">home content</section>
        <section id="2">about content</section>
        <section id="3">work content</section>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could u make a fiddle for this @ jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On page load you need to set one of the link active

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (!location.hash) {
        $('a.panel:first').addClass('active');
    } else {
        $('a.panel[href=' + location.hash + ']').addClass('active');
    }

    $('a.panel').bind('click', function(event) {
        $('a.panel').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a function to update the classes, but defining a function doesn't make it run. It only runs when the user clicks on an `a.panel` element.

If you want to run on page load / refresh, you need some way of finding out what the active element is. Is the idea that the same element would be active after page refresh? If so, maybe you could try store.js . There may well be simpler answers, but I can't think of any off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... you can also use jQuery.waypoints:
http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#get-started

Comment: i was looking for a way without using another plugin but thank you this is one solution.

Answer (score 0):

After refresh, you lose HTML state you modified by Javascript.

You have 2 choice:

Get value from URL hash and call `trigger`

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
$('nav').eq(hash-1).trigger('click');
```

Or store data in cache or webstorage, ...